# How to open gnome-terminal full-screen?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-terminal

I need gnome-terminal to open full-screen by default.

I overloaded it via `/usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal`:

```
#!/bin/dash
exec /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --full-screen "$@"
```

But this only works for *xdg-mime* (`.desktop` files with `Terminal=true`) and opening gnome-terminal from gnome-menu.

It does not work when I start new terminal by right-clicking in existing terminal and selecting "Open Terminal" option in the drop-down menu.

I tried to search in gnome-terminal source, but did not find where this menu option is handled.

How to start gnome-terminal full-screen in all cases?